# Sitecore APIs throwing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: sitecore-api

We have exposed Sitecore's authoring server via two URLs:

1. https:// www[dot]authoring[dot]sitename[dot]com/sitecore
2. https:// authoring[dot]sitename[dot]com/sitecore

Both the URLs were working fine till last week. But, the Sitecore APIs on `www` URL started throwing `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. The second URL is working fine. Also, Sitecore shell or content editing is working on both URLs.

Below are the screenshots of both URLs:

**With "www"**
[image]

**Without "www"**
[image]

What could be the possible reason for this issue?

Comment: If it was working fine than did you try by clearing browser cache and changing the browser?

Comment: yes, I have tried it on multiple browsers, private/incognito mode and cache reset.  But it didn't work

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using Identity Server ?

Comment: Is there any IIS redirect rule in place , or any redirect item present in Sitecore ?

Comment: We are using sitecore 8.2 update 5
there is no reirect rile in place.